# im stuck on homework (stuck on loop)

Tags: javascript

im currently doing home work and im stuck with this part i dont know why im stuck in infinite loop
INSTRUCTIONS:
Detemine if the currentPage is an ending
Create a function to do this! That will keep your code nice and clean.

Have a single parameter for your function, currentPage.

Use a loop to check if the current page matches any of the page numbers in endingPages

If you find the page within endingPages, return true. If you do not, return false.

Use this function in your while loop to determine if the current page is an ending.

MY CODE:

```
console.log(pages[0]);

let endingPages = [4, 9, 13, 17, 19, 20];
let currentPage = 0;

// Your Code Here.


function ending(currentPage){
    for(let i = 0; i <=endingPages.length; i++){
        while(currentPage !== null)
            currentPage =prompt(`pages What page would you like to go ?`);
                if (currentPage !== null) {
                currentPage = parseInt(currentPage);
                }else{
                currentPage = null;
                }
       
    }
}
ending(currentPage);
```

Comment: `i <=endingPages.length` should be `i < endingPages.length`.

Comment: i did that and im still stuck on infinite loop

Comment: `currentPage` is in two different scopes and you should use the ending function __in__ in the while loop. You are currently using the while loop inside the ending function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove while loop and add if condition instead and replace "<=" operator with "<" operator in for loop.

```js
let endingPages = [4, 9, 13, 17, 19, 20];
let currentPage = 0;

// Your Code Here.


function ending(currentPage){
    for(let i = 0; i < endingPages.length; i++){
        if (currentPage !== null && currentPage !== undefined) {
            currentPage =prompt(`pages What page would you like to go ?`);
            // your code......
         }       
       
    }
}
ending(currentPage);
```

Comment: that worked and got me out of the infinite loop but the next step is taliking about a while loop............................ If the page is an ending, then print that page and exit the game
Since your while loop ends if currentPage is null, assign null to the current page and then your loop will end on the next iteration.

Comment: You can first try implementing the code and when face the issue you can post here.

Comment: This issue was regarding infinite loop, you can upvote the answer as you told it’s resolved